# SSRS url makes forward slash instead of backslash

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In my SQL query I had
concat('flaunch2:C:\SOLIDWORKS\PDM',REPLACE(p.Path, '', '/')) AS 'Open Folder',
but when running the hyperlink to open the URL the slashes still remained forward.

I removed the replace in SQL and created an expression in SSRS.
=Replace(Fields!Open_Folder.Value, "", "/") + "','_blank'));"
I am getting the same results with the forward slash.

FYI- Flaunch is code I had written that opens links from SSRS to file explorer.

I tried this is SSRS as a URL link. Without the = it works but you have to copy and paste. Once you have the = the slashes go to forward.
=Replace(Fields!Open_Folder.Value, "", "/") + "','_blank'));"

Answer (score 0):

Your replace statement does nothing as far as I can tell

```
=Replace(Fields!Open_Folder.Value, "", "/")
```

Says, take `Fields!Open_Folder.Value`, look for `""` and replace with `"/"`

The same for the version you tried in your SQL statement.

I guess you wanted

```
=Replace(Fields!Open_Folder.Value, "/", "\")
```

Comment: I am sorry. I am not sure why I copied the one with " " when I meant "\", "/".

Comment: That's still the wrong way round, that will replace backslash (`\`) with a forward slash  (`/`)

Comment: I figured out the real issue. Since its a URL they always use a forward slash. I think the main issue is how to make a hyperlink in SSRS that allows a backslash so I can navigate folders not the internet.

Comment: you'll probably have to escape the backslashes by using two `\\\`